# Mockito - Asserting invocations for a stubbed method

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a stubbed method whose invocation count I would like to assert. But it looks like the `times(x)` parameter makes no difference at all when the method is stubbed. Why is this? And what's the right to way to do this?

```
@Test
public void MyTest() {
  PowerMockito.when(mock.someMethod()).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);

  testClass.anotherMethod();

  Mockito.verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod(); // succeeds regardless of count
}
```

Comment: Are you sure?  What you've done looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't works.

Comment: Show us your full test class and content of testClass. Also don't mixup Mockito and PowerMockito, when you use one for a mock you have to use it for the verify.

Comment: OK.  Until you can show a reproducible example though, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: I was able to fix it. I needed to wrap `testClass.anotherMethod();` in a `try-catch` because it throws Exception.